# How does rust behave as a PN junction?

Tags: electronics, radio

Reading about [old-fangled radios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio) the reference quoted below indicates it was/is possible to use a rusted razor (or perhaps any similar thin corroded metal strip) as a detector.

**Some resourceful GIs found that a crude crystal set could be made from a coil made of salvaged wire, a rusty razor blade and a pencil lead for a diode. By lightly touching the pencil lead to spots of blue on the blade, or to spots of rust, they formed what is called a point contact diode and the rectified signal could be heard on headphones or crystal ear pieces.**

How does a rusted razor perform the same task as a PN junction? Is it merely that rust (being minute oxidized metallic particles) migrates under the influence of the electrical field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a great answer since all the papers I could find are behind paywalls, but ferric oxide is a semiconductor and depending on it's exact stochiometry can be n type or p type.

If you know someone in academia with access have a look at:

http://jes.ecsdl.org/content/126/3/419.abstract

http://jes.ecsdl.org/content/131/8/1777.abstract